# Why is my SearchController not displaying the correct cell prototype for the first cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

As the title suggests, I am having trouble with my UISearchController displaying the wrong cell prototype for the first cell in the search results.

**Background Information:**  I have two cell prototypes, one without an image (identifier: basicCell) and another with a UIImageView (identifier: imageCell). Cells work perfectly when not searching.

**Detailed Description of the Problem:** When I click on the search bar everything is fine until I start searching for something. When I do, the first cell always has the imageCell identifier (a gray empty image view is shown denoting the lack of an image), no matter what. NB: Before searching anything, the first cell in the tableview has a custom image... Maybe that's of note?
Anyway I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Would anyone mind helping?

**Code:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            if hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCellImage
                let event = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

                cell.content.text = profile.content
                cell.name.text = profile.name

                //This is the image
                cell.attachment.image = profile.image
                cell.attachment.layer.cornerRadius = 1
                cell.attachment.clipsToBounds = true

                return cell

            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell
                let event = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

                cell.content.text = profile.content
                cell.name.text = profile.name
                return cell
            }

        } else {
            if hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(imageCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCellImage
                let event = events[indexPath.row]

                cell.content.text = profile.content
                cell.name.text = profile.name

                cell.attachement.image = profile.image
                cell.attachment.layer.cornerRadius = 1
                cell.attachment.clipsToBounds = true

                return cell

            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(basicCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell
                let event = events[indexPath.row]

                cell.content.text = profile.content
                cell.name.text = profile.name
                return cell

            }

        }

    }
```

And this is my code that checks for an image:

```
func hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        let imageArray = [event.image]
        for eventImage in imageArray {
            if eventImage != nil {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: IndexPath.row for the first row of your search table view is always going to be 0, so the fact that your first row of the main table view has an image for the first row is why you see this problem. You need to rethink your logic, so that you pass the index of the data source that corresponds to the cell the search is returning.

Comment: @rdelmar could you please elaborate? I'm still new to this. Is there anything you recommend me doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an if-else clause in your `hasImageAtIndexPath:` function just like you have in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If the table view is the search table, then `event` needs to be defined the same way as you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,

```
func hasImageAtIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath sender:UITableView) -> Bool
    if (self.resultSearchController.active){
         let event = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
    }else{
         let event = events[indexPath.row]
    }

    let imageArray = [event.image]
    for eventImage in imageArray {
        if eventImage != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```